# Add product name to the url (basic php routing)

Tags: php, mysqli, routes

I'm trying to get my current url structure looks like this:

```
acme.com/list.php?id=1
```

How can I add product name to the url so it look like this:

```
acme.com/list.php?id=1&name=acme-product
```

Here's what my query looks like and even though I can add name parametr to the url, it has no effect:

```
$id = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['id']);
if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1")){
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);}
```

I've tried the following code but it gets nothing

```
$id = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['id']);
$title = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['title']);
if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE id=$id AND title=$title LIMIT 1")){
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);}
```

Comment: Before you go any further, read up on SQL injection. Especially when you're feeding parameters through the URL with GET requests.

Comment: I know, I know. But for now I just wanna deal with these problems. I'm a newbie.

Comment: `name !== title` : `$title = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['name']);`

Comment: Thank you! Plus I forgot to put $title in quotes i.e. '$title'. Now everything works.